# how can we implement "logoutpreaction" and "logoutpostaction" in liferay dxp 7.3

Tags: liferay-7

Hi Can any one provide sample class for "logoutpreaction" and "logoutpostaction" in liferay dxp 7.3.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Logout Pre Action sample class:

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.LifecycleAction;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.LifecycleEvent;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Log;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogFactoryUtil;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

@Component(
    immediate = true, property = "key=logout.events.pre",
    service = LifecycleAction.class
)
public class LogoutPreAction implements LifecycleAction {

    @Override
    public void processLifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent lifecycleEvent)
        throws ActionException {

        _log.info("logout.event.pre=" + lifecycleEvent);
    }

    private static final Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(LogoutPreAction.class);

}
```

Logout Post Action sample class:

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.LifecycleAction;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.LifecycleEvent;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Log;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogFactoryUtil;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

@Component(
    immediate = true, property = "key=logout.events.post",
    service = LifecycleAction.class
)
public class LogoutPostAction implements LifecycleAction {

    @Override
    public void processLifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent lifecycleEvent)
        throws ActionException {

        _log.info("logout.event.post=" + lifecycleEvent);
    }

    private static final Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(LogoutPostAction.class);

}
```